# Why is my 'Aptana' showing this cross on top line of my css?

Tags: aptana

[image][image]After update my Aptana showing this cross in all css file. Is there any mistake in my css ?

Comment: What's the message when go over it?

Comment: See i added new image.

Answer (score 1):

You have "solid" value for border color attribute somewhere in your css which is not valid (based on W3C standard)!

[solid is a border-style not a border-color.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-color)

Comment: I changed but now showing this Border-style #000 is not a style value.

Comment: It should be something like this: `border-style: solid; border-color: #000`